# Symfony crawler select tag attributes from dropdown

Tags: symfony, dom, attributes, web-crawler, selected

I need to target "selected" attribute in drop down menu so I can compare if item marked as selected is the item what I need to have selected.
Can you help me with methods, what I can use for this ?

```
<option value="Title" selected>Title</option>
<option value="First Name">First Name</option>
<option value="Middle Name">Middle Name</option>
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

I've found an answer finally -

```
$crawler->filter('option[selected]')->attr('value');
```

works for me :)

Comment: Only answer I got through Google, it works, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that (not tested)

```
$target = $crawler->filterXPath('//.../option/@selected')->text();
```

or

```
$target = $crawler->filterXPath('//.../option')->attr('selected')->text();
```